# Why is ChartJS skipping an xAxis label in this snippet?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Pretty straight forward:

http://codepen.io/fishgills/pen/WGdKNA

In the JavaScript section, for the labels, it currently says:

```
                    ticks: {
                        maxTicksLimit: 12
                    },
```

If you change it to:

```
                    ticks: {
                        maxTicksLimit: 6
                    },
```

ChartJS doesn't render the lines evenly. Anyone know why? It looks like it skips a data point for the x axis

Comment: I don't get what's the problem. There are actually two months between February & May (*March & April*), as you have two values between your ticks. I don't see where's the skipped data.

Comment: I'm trying to get it to have labels for February and April. Skip over March and May.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are actually looking for can be done with the `userCallback` property in the options :

```js
options: {
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                userCallback: function(value, index) {
                    if (index % 2) return "";
                    return value;
                }
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

See the [documentation](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#scales-category-scale) about it (*scroll up a bit*) for more information.

You can check [this updated plunker](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xEYbPx), and its result :

[image]